# Getting string response from server using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having a fetch() method that makes a post request to a Web Api 2 server. If the server considers the POST data valid, it returns a string containing a login token in the string format. The problem is that I can't get the string that was returned in my fetch method, when I am trying to apply response.json getting nothing, and in a console.log just before the dispatch the response.json being unidentified.

Here is my fetch code:

```
export const login = (user) => (dispatch) => {
dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_STARTED' });
return fetch(`${httpApiUrl}/api/userdata/verify`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
})
    .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            Alert.alert('ERROR', 'User or password is incorrect');
            dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_FAILED', data: 'User or password is incorrect' });
        }
        else return response;
    }).then((response) => response.json).then((response) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCEEDED', data: response.json });

    })
    .catch(error => {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_FAILED', data: error.message });
    });
};
```

Here is my server post method code

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("verify")]
[ResponseType(typeof(string))]
[AllowAnonymous]
public HttpResponseMessage VerifyUser(HttpRequestMessage request, UserDataView data)
{
    return CreateHttpResponse(request, () =>
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        if (service.wasUpdated(data)) //de fapt verifica daca e userul in baza de date
        {
            response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, JwtManager.GenerateToken(data.username));
        }
        else
            response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, false);
        return response;
    });
}
```

I checked on the server if the function returns the string, and it does, the string being added to the response.

How can I get in the 
    dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCEEDED', data: response.json });
method in data my string response and response.json not being unidentified anymore? Thank you.

Comment: Is the response wrapped with `""` like `"{ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCEEDED', data: response.json }"` in console?

Comment: response.json() instead?

Comment: Response.json() gives me an unidentified error for the function. And also the response isn't wrapped in "", if I print it in console right before dispatch, in the same function as it, it shows me undefined.

Comment: if your response is a plain string, not a JSON object, then anticipate the response type being text, not json